# How to import a mySQL database without creating a new one

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a mySQL database into a clients hosting where privelidges in PHP Admin are extremely limited.

I am not able to create a new database, only work with the one they've given me.

When I upload the file with the database details in it.. I get an error telling me that the database already exists.

When I try and upload the database with the details for a new one... I get the error message that I am not allowed to create a new database.

What can I do to upload the contents of this database to the new one?

Comment: Does the contents of your file add to or replace the existing database contents?

Comment: I have some text at the top of the file which says

--
-- Database: `nic0ej370`
--
CREATE DATABASE `nic0ej370` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `nic0ej370`;


If I could possibly change "CREATE DATABASE" to something else? Would that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit your SQL dump file and get rid of the database create statement (and the drop database as well if one is there).  Then import.